# Why does Corona SDK not build a .apk file?

Tags: android, corona-sdk

I'm trying to put a game I created in Corona SDK on my Galaxy S5. I go to the Corona Simulator, click Build for Android.. Then I fill out the information, and then I hit build. The problem is, it's not an apk file, it's a GameSpy Arcade Online file. Why does it do that? How could I fix it?

Thank you,
-Bryce

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried renaming it? Maybe theres a installed program that detects APK files as what you have said. And just to make sure, check show known extension in you folder options in windows

Answer (score 1):

It *is* an apk, but your computer associates that filetype with Gamespy Arcade Online. When I search on "gamespy arcade online filetype" I see that [it is also APK](http://www.file-extensions.org/apk-file-extension-gamespy-arcade-service-file):

> What is .apk file?
>
> The APK file extension is used by GameSpy Arcade service, a shareware
>   multiplayer game server browsing utility

To change this, search for "windows associate filetype". For example, one of the results is: http://www.7tutorials.com/how-associate-file-type-or-protocol-program